# Showing a type cast error by hive when I tries to retrieve the data I stored . Flutter hive

Tags: flutter, flutter-hive

I am creating a music player and using hive for database. I am entering the values as key value pairs into database where the key is user input from text field and it is the name of playlist they are creating. The database takes in values as `List<AudioModel>` where audio model is the class defined by myself. So whenever user creates a play list I am actually putting a key value pair in database where key is user input and the value is an empty list of `AudioModel`.

```
void putIt(context) async {
    bool isItUnique = await isUnique(_controller.text);

    if (_controller.text.isNotEmpty && isItUnique) {
        final newPlaylistName = _controller.text;
        await allSongsBox!.put(newPlaylistName, newPlaylist);
        setStateOfPlaylistScreen();
        print(await allSongsBox!.values);
        final snackBar = SnackBar(
            content: Text("New playlist named '${_controller.text}' added."));
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
        Navigator.of(context).pop();
    }
}
```

The above is the code for creating a newplaylist but the error comes when I tries to retrieve the data. It throws an exception as `List<dynamic>` is not a sub type of `List<AudioModel>`

The code for retrieving data:

```
void getPlaylist(context) async{
 List <AudioModel> playlistSongs= await allSongsBox!.get(playlistName)!;
 print(playlistSongs);
 if(isExists()){
 ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text("Song already exists"),));
 }
```

I am stuck here please help.

error message :

[image: error message]

Comment: Please update the question with the exact error message.

Comment: question updated please have a look

Comment: Can you also explain the `get` method and where it comes from? Essentially the issue is `allSongsBox.get` returns a type of `List<dynamic>` where as playlistSongs is expected to be `List<AudioModel>`. There is also a secondary issue which is around `null-safety` as the `get` method can return a null `null`.  Try defining playlistSongs as `List<AudioModel>?`.